# Automatically generate a Wikipedia-style Table of Contents with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table, html-lists, tableofcontents

The heading title is self-explanatory. An illustrative example of this done manually:

```
<head>
  <style>
    .toc {
      border: thin solid lightgray;
      background-color: whitesmoke;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>

  <h1>Article title</h1>
  <hr />
  <p>Some introductory text.</p>

  <span id="toc">
    <table class="toc">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Contents</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <ol>
              <li><a href="#1">Heading</a></li>
              <ol>
                <li><a href="#1.1">Sub-heading</a></li>
                <ol>
                  <li><a href="#1.1.1">Sub-sub-heading</a></li>
                </ol>
              </ol>
              <li><a href="#2">Second heading</a></li>
              <ol>
                <li><a href="#2.1">Second sub-heading</a></li>
                <ol>
                  <li><a href="#2.1.1">Second sub-sub-heading</a></li>
                </ol>
              </ol>
              <li><a href="#3">See also</a></li>
              <li><a href="#4">Notes &amp; References</a></li>
              <li><a href="#5">Further reading</a></li>
              <li><a href="#6">External links</a></li>
            </ol>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </span>

  <div id="Contents">
    <h1 id="1">Heading</h1>
    <hr />
    <h2 id="1.1">Sub-heading</h2>
    <h3 id="1.1.1">Sub-sub-heading</h3>
    <h1 id="2">Second heading</h1>
    <hr />
    <h2 id="2.1">Second sub-heading</h2>
    <h3 id="2.1.1">Second sub-sub-heading</h3>
    <h1 id="3">See also</h1>
    <hr />
    <h1 id="4">Notes &amp; References</h1>
    <hr />
    <h1 id="5">Further reading</h1>
    <hr />
    <h1 id="6">External links</h1>
    <hr />
  </div>

</body>
```

Problems:

1. Notice the nested lists re-start their count from 1 instead of progressing from the parent enumeration (e.g. "1, 1.1, 1.1.1").
2. Doing this manually is time consuming.
3. All promptly available "Table of Contents" libraries do not function or style by default like the one in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) articles. Most of these libraries are not exactly "lightweight" and this is also an incovenience.

Comment: Generate from what source material?  And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @AlexanderNied Everything within `<div id="Contents"></div>`

Comment: Everything within `<div id="Contents"></div>` is the source material. I just edited the above code under the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) adjusted to render expected result

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;                /* Creates a new instance of the
                                            section counter with each ol
                                            element */
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: section;            /* Increments only this instance
                                            of the section counter */
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";   /* Combines the values of all instances
                                            of the section counter, separated
                                            by a period */
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item</li>          <!-- 1     -->
  <li>item               <!-- 2     -->
    <ol>
      <li>item</li>      <!-- 2.1   -->
      <li>item</li>      <!-- 2.2   -->
      <li>item           <!-- 2.3   -->
        <ol>
          <li>item</li>  <!-- 2.3.1 -->
          <li>item</li>  <!-- 2.3.2 -->
        </ol>
        <ol>
          <li>item</li>  <!-- 2.3.1 -->
          <li>item</li>  <!-- 2.3.2 -->
          <li>item</li>  <!-- 2.3.3 -->
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>item</li>      <!-- 2.4   -->
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>item</li>          <!-- 3     -->
  <li>item</li>          <!-- 4     -->
</ol>
<ol>
  <li>item</li>          <!-- 1     -->
  <li>item</li>          <!-- 2     -->
</ol>
```